# Android app to download Youtube videos in H265

Tags: android

Is there and Android app that can directly download YouTube videos in x265 hevc format?

Comment: Do you want to download in that format, or does Youtbue have that format and you want to play it? What can the app cost? Please [read this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and improve your question

Comment: I want to download videos in H265 encoded HEVC format from Youtube.

Comment: Link for example video in H265?

Comment: What are you asking for?